# Defining objects positions in window coordinate system

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0

I'm building my really first app in OpenGL Es 2.0. I want to create a simple app that applies stickers over a picture.

I can't understand how to place stickers working in window coordinate system. I can place images within the -1+1 system but since I want to work with touches it'd be really useful to translate this space onto the window coordinate system.

Currently I suppose that the right way to go is working with an ortho projection but I'm not sure it is enough to move to screen coordinate system.

Could you help me to understand how to set up my environment to get what I need?